# Scribbled SVG line?

Tags: svg

Is there a way to let a line, polygon,... , looks like it has been scribbled or hand drawn?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="10" y1="20" x2="200" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(99,99,99);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, break the line into several lines (or use a path with as many segments as you want). It should be fairly trivial to write a script that adds a bit of randomness to the points in each path segment. Another way is to use svg filters, like this for example:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-0.15" width="1.3" y="-0.15" height="1.3" id="squiggle">
            <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.03" type="fractalNoise" seed="47" numOctaves="4" />
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
            <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B" scale="23.5" />
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
        </filter>
        <style>
            line, circle {
              fill: none;
              stroke: rgb(99, 99, 99);
              stroke-width: 2;
              filter: url(#squiggle);
            }
            text {
              filter: url(#squiggle);
              fill: rgb(99, 99, 99);
              font: 36px italic;
            }
       </style>
    </defs>
    <line x1="10" y1="20" x2="200" y2="300" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="70" r="25" />
    <line x1="150" y1="30" x2="100" y2="300" />
    <text x="170" y="80">Squiggly!</text>
</svg>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6XWQ/). Here's another [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/textured-type/textured-type.svg).

Comment: The two links in this answer are broken, I'm trying to google for any article that this answer suggests you found, any idea about a replacement link? I'm looking for a way to make this http://jason.sperske.com/wad/DOOM1.WAD/ look hand drawn :)